# CefSharp with Chromium Renders text to small after Upgrade v119.4.30

Tags: cefsharp

The application worked as expected up to version v107+. However, after upgrading from v108 to v119, the application did not work as expected. CefSharp with Chromium rendered the text too small.

Prior to Chromium v108:

Text displayed correctly within the application.
Text size matched user expectations and system settings.
After upgrading to Chromium v108 and later versions (up to v119):

Text rendered significantly smaller than expected.
Text appears unreadable or difficult to read due to the reduced size.

Chromium rendered the text - responsive

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/4410

Comment: After adding these lines of code before initialization, it is working as expected. Thank you very much.
[DllImport(@"user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(IntPtr dpiAWarenessContext);

private const int DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = -1;
private const int DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE_GDISCALED = -5;

Comment: Great. You should hopefully be able to post an answer to your own question, make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a method or a variable, you need to follow this syntax:

Declare a method that takes an IntPtr parameter and returns a bool value

```
public static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(IntPtr dpiAwarenessContext);
```

Declare a variable that holds an int constant with the value -1

```
private const int DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = -1;
```

Before initializing, call this method:

```
if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
    {
        var r = SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext((System.IntPtr)DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);
        if (!r)
        {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Trace.TraceWarning($@"Error settings DPI awareness: {error}.");
        }
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
    }
```

Reference Link:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/4410#issuecomment-1542363136